# Page-specific skins in MediaWiki?

Tags: css, mediawiki, wiki

Is there a way to force a particular skin to be applied while displaying specific MediaWiki articles?

In my wiki many articles will have a "flip" version with alternative content (think "good" and "evil" perspectives of the same topic). I was thinking about using namespaces to separate these versions, but I need a definitive way to visually contrast them.

Comment: There is a link in special preferences that allows you to preview skins. It can be hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [SkinPerPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SkinPerPage) extension that serves exactly this purpose: to force a particular skin on a given page.

In short:

(1) [Download](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/SkinPerPage) the extension, unpack files in `/wiki-folder/extensions/`

(2) Add `wfLoadExtension( 'SkinPerPage' );` instruction to your `LocalSettings.php`

(3) Add `<skin>skin-name</skin>` tag to the page that you need to show a skin different from the default.

Sweet :)

Tested on the brand new MediaWiki 1.30.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

Disable per-user skin settings with

```
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'skin';
```

then set `$wgDefaultSkin` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I believe that skin preference is the only way. If you know how cookies may be a good idea for page specific skins but it would require quite a bit of setup.